# Bitbucket cannot handle FTP Deployment with username containing a "@" symbol

Tags: bitbucket

Bitbucket cannot handle FTP Deployment with ftp username containing "@" symbol

No chance with something like this (bitbucket-pipelines.yml):

```
- git ftp init sftp://elvis@presley:mypassword@myhostserver.com
```

Bitbucket mistakenly believes that the host begins after the @ sign

Any idea to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the URL correctly. `@` is a reserved character in this context, so you need to escape it as `%40`:

```
sftp://elvis%40presley:mypassword@myhostserver.com
```

This isn't related to Bitbucket. This is a general requirement of the [authority component of all URIs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.1).

Comment: Thank you, but I still got an error:

+ git ftp init sftp://elvis%40presley:mypassword@myhostserver.com
fatal: Can't access remote 'sftp://elvis', exiting...

Comment: Hello, have you tried it and did it work for you?  Or is it just a guess that it has to be done that way.  According to my internet research, it didn't work for anyone

Comment: It's based on URL encodings; your URL is definitely illegal. I don't know anything about Bitbucket; you should direct questions about their API to them. If they have bugs in their API that prevent it from handling legal URLs, then they're your best source of support.

Comment: Thanks, I also think it's a good idea to ask bitbucket